# Using the graph API, is it possible to add an existing photo to an existing album?

Tags: facebook, photo, facebook-opengraph

Say I have a photo with a given ID on Facebook. Can I add that photo to an existing album I created (like a link), or do albums/photos have a strict child/parent relationship?

The documentation seems to suggest it's impossible, but FB docs are not always that good, so wondering if anyone knows.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using graph api, just use the [Facebook to do it](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=187697921280875).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to do it programmatically (or why would I ask in SO. ;))